# Filter a specific range of dates across mult-year data set

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, lubridate

I have a data frame that consist of data across multiple years. I am trying to filter specific dates in each of these years, but I am unsure of how to do this. In the code below, I have filtered the data for a single year for data that falls in two different ranges (i.e., `df2` and `df3`). How could I modify this code to work on all of the years in my data set?

I want the code to filter the `ID`s with all of the dates in the range, and not to include any data that is missing a day from the range.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

ID <-  rep(c("A","B","C", "D"), 5000)
date <-  rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2010"), dmy("31-01-2015"), by = "days"), 5000)
x <-  runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000)
y <-  runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000)

df <- data.frame(date = date, 
                 x = x,
                 y =y,
                 ID)


df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(date >= "2010-01-01", date <= "2010-01-31")

df3 <- df %>% 
  filter(date >= "2010-07-01", date <= "2010-07-31")
```

Comment: Are you looking for only two datasets or 2 per each year?

Comment: Two per each year, so each year will be filter for the specified dates, resulting in one data set with all of the specified dates in each year.

Comment: Why I asked is because it can be just two datasets with all years instead of multiple data

Comment: I guess that might be a little easier for me to work with. Would it be slightly the same as the answer you provided with some modifications?

Comment: That would be to create another column with year same, but that should also take into consideration the leap year so, you may check the update in my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the 'date' to `Date` class (`ymd`), do a `group_split` into a `list` by the `year`, then create the two datasets by `filter`ing on the date created with `make_date`, and return a `list` of 'df2' and 'df3' for each 'year' (nested list)

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
out <- df %>%
      mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% 
      group_split(yr = year(date), .keep = FALSE) %>% 
      map(~ {
        df2 <- .x %>% 
         filter(date >= make_date(year(first(date)), 1, 1), 
              date <= make_date(year(first(date)), 1, 31))
        df3 <-  .x %>% 
          filter(date >= make_date(year(first(date)), 7, 1),
          date <= make_date(year(first(date)), 7, 31))
    list(df2, df3)
} )
```

---

Another option is to create another column with 'year' same (considering the `leap` year as well)

```
library(stringr)
df1 <- df %>%
     mutate(date1 = ymd(str_replace(date, '^\\d{4}', '2020')))
```

and then use the OP's code to subset on 'date1'